# Dynamic {% use %} statement in twig?

Tags: php, twig

I want to achieve the following thing:

I have a basic template for all of my pages, named "`_page_base.twig`". It contains the header and footer.

Then I have a Template for different areas of the page: "`topic.twig`", "`section.twig`" and "`article.twig`" - each of them extending the "`_page_base.twig`", thats working well so far.

Now I want to write my articles. I would love to save them as .twig file as well, since I can edit the complete markup in my editor and just upload it.

Since I can't say that my article files just extend "`article.twig`" (multiple inheritance is not possible) I could tell the "`article.twig`" that it should use blocks from my different article-content twigfiles.
The problem is: "use" statements have to be hardcoded!

My current solution is to add `{% use "[PLACEHOLDER]" %}` into the "`article.twig`" and then loading the template into a string, replacing the placeholder to the correct article-content.twig and then passing the whole thing to the template engine. What a mess.

Have you guys any idea for a better solution?

Comment: Actually I used another approach: I load and parse my article content file and pass it as a variable to my "article.twig". I wrote a quick recipe to describe it: http://wearekiss.com/recipes/view/php/twig/twig-dynamic-use

Answer (score 1):

You can try with include tag. Since this tag accepts a dynamic name template to include, you just only need to define a variable which contains the name of article twig template.

```
{# on article.twig#}

{% set articles = ['someArticle.twig', ...] %}
{% for article in articles %}
    {% include article %}
{% endfor %}

{# on someArticle.twig #}
... Article text ...
```

In the case of you need to customize some content inside of `someArticle.twig` you could stage the next level: embed tag. You should define a block tag inside of `someArticle.twig`, this block will be the placeholder to the custom values.

```
{# on article.twig#}

{% set articles=['someArticle.twig', ...] %}
{% for article in articles %}
    {% embed article %}
        {% block inside_text_article %}
            ... custom text ...
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endfor %}


{# on someArticle.twig #}
    ... article text ...
    {% block inside_text_article %}default values{% endblock %}
    ... article text ...
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/17 - no dynamic namespaces

LiipThemeBundle might be a solution: 
http://symfony2bundles.org/liip/LiipThemeBundle

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am not understanding the question, displaying a single article only requires that it also extends __page_base.twig.

In the case that you would need to display multiple articles, you could have a template dedicated to showing a list of articles which would also extend __page_base.twig and pass the article list to this template.